# SQL - Remove duplicates after using a GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I had two tables that looked like this:

| Prod_SerialNo | Prod_TestOnAt | Prod_AccountNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SN0001 | 2021-04-08 | 045678 |
| SN0001 | 2021-01-14 | 067891 |
| SN0001 | 2021-11-29 | 091234 |
| SN0002 | 2022-01-19 | 045678 |
| SN0002 | 2020-07-30 | 045678 |
| SN0002 | 2022-03-30 | 012345 |
| SN0003 | 2022-04-01 | 078912 |
| SN0003 | 2022-02-19 | 089123 |
| SN0003 | 2022-03-18 | 023456 |

| S_AccountNo | S_AccountType | S_AccountName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 012345 | Homeowner | Adam Smith |
| 023456 | Homeowner | Jeremy Chan |
| 034567 | Manufacturer | Anne Hudson |
| 045678 | Distributor | Barney Jones |
| 056789 | Distributor | Jasmine Coleman |
| 067891 | Homeowner | Christian Lewis |
| 078912 | Distributor | Heather Ogden |
| 089123 | Homeowner | Stephen Gray |
| 091234 | Distributor | Antony Newman |

The Prod Table tabulates specific product tests by what serial number was used, when the product was tested, and who tested it. (There are other things in the table, including a primary key not shown here)

The S Table is a list of subscribers with a variety of information about them. S_AccountNo is the parent to Prod_AccountNo.

I want to query when the **last** test was performed for each Serial Number and what account name it was that performed the test, but I don't want multiple results (duplicates) for the same serial number. I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT 
   Prod_SerialNo, 
   MAX(Prod_TestOnAt) AS "Last Time Tested", 
   S_AccountName 
FROM Prod
INNER JOIN S ON S.S_AccountNo = Prod.Prod_AccountNo
GROUP BY Prod_SerialNo, S_AccountName
ORDER BY Prod_SerialNo
```

However, the query ends up outputting the same serial number on multiple rows even though I ask for the max TestOnAt date and I group by serial number. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by `Prod_SerialNo`, `S_AccountName` so you will get duplicate `Prod_SerialNo` if multiple rows exist with that `Prod_SerialNo` and different `S_AccountNames`. You could do a `MAX` on `Prod_TestOnAt` and get that value with it's `Prod_SerialNo`, then join the result on the table to get your desired info using a subquery like so:

```
SELECT
  p.[Prod_SerialNo],
  max.[LastTimeTested],
  s.[S_AccountName]
FROM PROD as p
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
       Prod_SerialNo, 
       MAX(Prod_TestOnAt) as [LastTimeTested]
    FROM Prod
    GROUP BY [Prod_SerialNo]
) as max
on max.[Prod_SerialNo] = p.[Prod_SerialNo] and max.[LastTimeTested] = p.[Prod_TestOnAt]
INNER JOIN S as s
ON s.[S_AccountNo] = p.[Prod_AccountNo]
ORDER BY p.[Prod_SerialNo]
```

Comment: **This query is illegal in standard SQL-92**  see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html, and correct your SQL

Comment: @Luuk Can you elaborate? The `SELECT` in the subquery contains the only column `Prod_SerialNo` found in the `GROUP BY` and an aggregate?

Comment: This query will return multiple results if any of the serial numbers have a tie for the max date. None were present in the sample data, but could be a consideration.

Comment: @Luuk You linked to standards for MySQL, the OP tagged it as sql-server.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no need to use `Group by` you can get result with `Row_Number` like this:

```sql
SELECT 
   t.Prod_SerialNo, 
   t.Prod_TestOnAt AS "Last Time Tested", 
   t.S_AccountName 
 FROM (
SELECT 
   Prod_SerialNo, 
   Prod_TestOnAt,
   S_AccountName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Prod_SerialNo ORDER BY Prod_TestOnAt DESC) rw
FROM Prod
INNER JOIN S ON S.S_AccountNo = Prod.Prod_AccountNo
) t
WHERE t.rw=1
ORDER BY t.Prod_SerialNo
```

Comment: Yes this would work!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the solution using `ROW_NUMBER` an alternative is to use `CROSS APPLY` to identify the last `Prod_TestOnAt` and the associated `Prod_AccountNo`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Prod_SerialNo, ca.Prod_TestOnAt, s.S_AccountName
FROM Prod p
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Prod_TestOnAt, Prod_AccountNo
             FROM Prod
             WHERE Prod_SerialNo = p.Prod_SerialNo
             ORDER BY Prod_TestOnAt DESC) ca
INNER JOIN S ON S.S_AccountNo = ca.Prod_AccountNo
```